# Spring security jet always redirecting to "/" after successful auth

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I have made a Rest API project with Spring Boot 2. I have used jwt for authentication. I can generate tokens fine. But when I send the generated token in a header with a request, it always redirects me to "/" path instead of the requested path (in my case "/rest/hello").

This is my custom AuthenticationProvider

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationProvider extends AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    private JwtValidator jwtValidator;
    @Override
    protected void additionalAuthenticationChecks(UserDetails userDetails, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

    }

    @Override
    protected UserDetails retrieveUser(String username, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        JwtAuthenticationToken jwtAuthenticationToken = (JwtAuthenticationToken)authentication;
        String token = jwtAuthenticationToken.getToken();
        JwtUser jwtUser = jwtValidator.validate(token);
        if (jwtUser == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("JWT Token not correct");
        }
        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList(jwtUser.getRole());
        return new JwtUserDetails(jwtUser.getUserName(), jwtUser.getId(), grantedAuthorities, token);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return JwtAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);
    }
}
```

This is my custom Filter

```
public class JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {
    public  JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter() {
        super("/rest/**");
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
        String header = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (header == null || !header.startsWith("Token ")) {
            throw new RuntimeException("JWT Token is missing");
        }
        String authenticationToken = header.substring(6);
        JwtAuthenticationToken token = new JwtAuthenticationToken(authenticationToken);
        return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(token);
    }

    public void setAuthenticationManager(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        super.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }



    public void setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(JwtSuccessHandler jwtSuccessHandler) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
        super.successfulAuthentication(request, response, chain, authResult);
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

This is my Security config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class JwtSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;
    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint;

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
        return new ProviderManager(Collections.singletonList(authenticationProvider));
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilter(){
        JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter filter = new JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter();
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(new JwtSuccessHandler());
        return filter;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/rest/**").authenticated().and().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint)
                .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        http.headers().cacheControl();
    }
}
```

I have custom classes for user details and token as well.

Comment: You have configured `SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS`, so the URL is not saved in your HTTP session and couldn't redirected to after login. In this case your request is redirected to default URL `/`.

Comment: Removed that. Still doesnt work.